# Which VLOOKUP formula is more performance optimized? Range containing multiple unneeded columns, or array of only search key & single column range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Which formula is more performance optimized?**

A) `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A1:A,Sheet1!A1:D,4,0)`

B) `=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(A1:A,{Sheet1!A1:A,Sheet1!D1:D},2,0)`

I am assuming option B is more performance optimized, since VLOOKUP has to search less columns. But perhaps there is something I am overlooking such option B is having to do an array before it performs the vlookup itself. What are your thoughts?

---

**Sheet Example**

`Sheet1` contains a database of 4 columns.

```
| A  |      B     |     C     |   D   |
| ID | First Name | Last Name | Email |
```

`Sheet2` Has a list of ID's in Column A, and the VLOOKUP formula in Column B.

```
| A  |   B   |
| ID | Email |
```

Comment: Is there any differences? Performance issue is more important when come to write `Apps Script`. Formula does not matter in your sheet unless your have more than 10k line then it will overburden the sheet

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As for the sheet, it contains far more than 10k lines. It contains 400k rows (1.6 million cells contain data). So the importance of finding tweaks to formulas to improve performance is quite essential. For example, I will use INDEX MATCH instead of VLOOKUP when able to since its ~30% faster. In this formula, its an array, and does not work with INDEX MATCH. So I am stuck with trying to improve the VLOOKUP formula.

Comment: Index match definitely is better than `Vlookup`, let me try to see if possible with `arrayformula`

Comment: Ya, only `Vlookup` can combine with `arrayformula` with single formula, but since it is so slow, it will be better to copy `index match` to all cells if you want to speed it up

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately for this particular use, I cannot drag down the formula since new rows are added daily. I need it to remain dynamic and apply to the entire column. So we are back to optimizing `Vlookup`